# AdColony integration: prompt showing incorrect layout

Tags: ios, adcolony

When prompting users to show a video I'm seeing an incorrect layout.  It looks like the prompt is putting a portrait request into a landscape view.  As a result users aren't able to do anything in the app at this point, and have to kill it and restart.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have recently released an update to our SDK that corrects this issue and is fully compatible with iOS 8.1.  You will need to update to this version, you can download it from our GitHub site at https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-iOS-SDK.